# HideVersion property will not publish also other publish if EN is set to HideVersion = true

Tags: sitecore-client

I have an `item` with 3 languages. `EN, FR, NL`. The `Enable language fallback` is enabled to this item's `template standard value`. Now, when I set the `HideVersion = true` to `EN` item, it will not publish not only `EN` but also the other 2 languages. But when I set FR for example to `HideVersion = true`, it will be the only one to be not published. Why is that? I am using `Sitecore 8.2`

Comment: Am guessing "EN" is your fallback language. If you don't publish that, nothing will publish.

Comment: Yes it is. Ah so that's how it works... Okay I understand it now. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clarified in comments;

When "EN" is selected as the fallback language, and language fallback is enabled - preventing the "EN" version of an item from publishing (or hiding it) will result in the entire item being restricted from publishing.